# Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) hangs

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, home-networking, wireless-access-point

I am sharing my Wifi internet by creating a virtual network through the following commands

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=MyWifi key=XXXXXXX
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

It works perfectly and creates a new virtual wifi named MyWifi which can be used to connect to the internet.

After some time, this network freezes and can't be used.

When I try to stop it so that I can start it again, I get the following:

```
C:\Windows\system32>net stop sharedaccess
The Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) service is stopping........
The Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) service could not be stopped.
```

I checked event viewer for something that might be the reason behind this issue but there is nothing. Even killing the process through taskkill command or from Task manager cannot be performed. The only way to resolve this issue is to unplug my wireless adapter (Alfa AWUS036H - Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit) and plug it in again.

I tried to remove all drivers, re-install them again by using Windows update, verified power management settings for my adapter but the issue still exists.

Can you please help me how to troubleshoot this issue and to resolve it.

Comment: Do you have another wireless adapter to try?  That'd be the easiest thing to try

Comment: I agree with you, but I don't have one.

Comment: So go to a store, buy one, and if it doesn't work, return it saying it  doesn't work right.  That's what I'd do.

Comment: I just bought a new and cheap wireless adapter from TP Link, working perfectly. That means there is some issue with other adapter (Alfa)

Comment: Is the Alfa still under warranty?  You could maybe RMA it and have two functional adapters around for future use.